# Adding links to a row in a column on click (CellTable)

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, row, addition, celltable

I have a CellTable where I want to add several links to a row when I click an add button. Right now Im facing the problem that when I click the add button the link will be added to all rows in that column. Somehow it feels like I only can add things to columns.

```
// shows project column
    final MultipleLinkTextCell projectCell = new MultipleLinkTextCell();
    final Column<Booking, String> projectColumn = new Column<Booking, String>(
        projectCell) {

    @Override
    public String getValue(Booking project) {
       return "";
    }

    };
    getView().getTimeTable().addColumn(projectColumn, "Tasks");
```

An Example with Buttons

```
 @Override
protected void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
    SafeHtml data, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
String string = "";
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    string += "<button type=\"button\" style=\" height:20px; width:22px\">";
}

sb.appendHtmlConstant(string);
if (data != null) {
    sb.append(data);

}
}
```

Im thinking about to use the Anchor widget because I can handle the placemanager from gwtp with it. But still I dont know how to add widgets to a specific row.

//Update:
I did it like this now, it works, but its better to use the revealmanager. The hardcoded link is kinda bad because I always need to change the reference to the link when I change the webserver. I get a string with several values splitted by a commar.

```
   @Override
protected void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
    SafeHtml data, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
String stringData = data.asString();
String[] splitResult = stringData.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < splitResult.length; i++) {
    if (!splitResult[i].equals("")) {
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div><a href=\"http://127.0.0.1:8888/gwtpTimeTracking.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#project;projectid="+splitResult[i].substring(0, 7)+"\">"
        + splitResult[i].substring(0, 7) + "</a></div>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use any Widgets in `CellWidgets`.
However you can create your custom cell that mimics it or create an `ActionCell` and add a `VaueUpdater` that fires a `PlaceRequest` Event.

For adding the link to a specific row you have to add a field (i..e `List<String> links`) to your DTO that is rendered in your `CellTable`. When you click on the "Add" button you have to modify the field of the specific DTO in your list.

```
MyDTO obj = // get the specific DTO from the DataProvider
obj.setLinks(LIST OF LINKS);
```

In the render method of your custom cell you check the field (i..e `links`) and either render out the links or not.

Where does the `value` data in your render method come from ?

Comment: how can I check the links in the render method? In my column I have to return a single string.

Comment: if you override the `render` method of your custom `Cell` one parameter is the String that has to be rendered. You can check if that's not null/not empty and then render a link otherwise render nothing.

Comment: hm ok, I updated my code. It works for me but I'm not really happy about that.

Comment: A couple of things
1.) Instead of returning a String you can returns a String[] or a DTO (contains url, title, etc) in your `Cell`. 
2.) you can use relative links instead of the absolute link.
3.) You can inject a `PlaceManager` into your custom `Cell` and construct the url.

Comment: I returned a DTO. It works :) But another Question: How can I use the placemanager in my custom Cell? I mean I cant just write it in the href or sth?

Comment: add the `PlaceManager` as a constructor parameter to your custom `Cell` and store it in a field. Then you can access it in your `render` method and create the proper URL and use setHref to set the URL.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time :) Everything works alright. I even added buttons to each link which trigger a fieldupdater to reveal a new presenter to edit the link value.